# forkJoin doesn't work with AngularFire2 valueChanges

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2, rxjs5

Please help me to fix an issue I'm struggling.

I have an array of Firebase object keys

```
const keys = ['-Kx9pqoMWlJLbKLQcAkP', '-Kx9pqoOYlDHTJ64Was5']
```

What I'm trying to do is to get all those Firebase objects in one stream using `forkJoin`. Here's what I have:

```
const obj1 = this.fbService.getObj(keys[0]);
const obj2 = this.fbService.getObj(keys[1]);

forkJoin([obj1, obj2])
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);  // <-- this never happens
    };
```

fbService method is:

```
getObj(key): Observable<MyObj> {
  return this.fb.object(`/path/to/obj/${key}`).valueChanges();
}
```

I assume that this `getObj` method doesn't work well with `forkJoin`, maybe because of `valueChanges`, am I using it correctly?

However:

- `getObj` works fine for getting single Firebase object, like:

  ```
  this.fbService.getObj(keys[0])
      .subsribe(res => console.log(res))// <-- works
  ```
- `forkJoin` works fine with simple HTTP requests, like

  ```
  const r1 = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1');
  forkJoin([r1])
      .subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);  // <-- works
      };
  ```

So, what am I doing wrong?
My goal is to get array of objects from array of keys:

```
['-Kx9pqoMWlJLbKLQcAkP', '-Kx9pqoOYlDHTJ64Was5'] => [{prop:'val'},{prop:'val2'}]
```

Comment: did you try that `this.fbService.getObj(keys[1])` also work? Because if any one of  the multiple observables in the `forkJoin` fails, the whole stream fails.

Comment: yes, I did try that. `this.fbService.getObj(keys[1])` works, but when it's inside  `forkJoin`, even alone, it doesn't work

Answer (score 10):

The `forkJoin` operator requires all source Observables to emit at least **one item** and to **complete**.

I don't know much about firebase but I'm suspicious that `valueChanges` never completes so that's why `forkJoin` never emits anything. One way to work with this is using `take(1)` to always complete the chain.

```
forkJoin(obj1.take(1), obj2.take(1)).subscribe(res => console.log(res);
```

Maybe in your case it would be better to use `zip()` operator that just requires all source Observables to emit the same number of items. However make sure you unsubscribe it because it doesn't complete itself until its source Observables complete.

Comment: I just checked the docs. Yes, they never gets completed. I guess OP alternatively have to use `.combineLatest()`

Comment: that's a good point, guys. But why does this `valueChanges` work when I use it alone? `this.fb.object(`...`).valueChanges().subscribe(WORKS)`

Comment: Because the first parameter is the `next` handler that is called for every item. If you want to check whether the Observable completes you can use eg. this: `.subscribe(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('complete'))`

Comment: `.combineLatest()` would be fine in this situations but be aware that it emits on every emission from any source Observables so you might be getting same values repeatedly.

Comment: @Matiishyn It means the stream never gets completed. When you subscribing to the observables, you are just "reacting" to the stream. If you want to know if the stream gets completed, you can put codes in to the `complete()` handler. And you realize they will never get executed.

Comment: Hey guys I am struggling to get the combinelatest to work with this exact issue. Can you please tell me how you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer has been provided by @martin, but the code sample needs to be updated to the new RxJS syntax:

```
forkJoin(obj1.pipe(take(1)), obj2.pipe(take(1))).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `startWith` operator

```
getObj(key): Observable<MyObj> {
  return this.fb.object(`/path/to/obj/${key}`)
     .valueChanges.pipe(starWith(value)); // value can be default obj to trigger stream
}
```

> probably because `valueChanges` does not start to emit until you manually trigger the stream so `forkJoin` does not fire until all of the source Observables emit at least once; so we make them all emit their default values once immediately.